# What is the correct way to check if a global variable exists?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, jslint

JSLint is not passing this as a valid code:

```
/* global someVar: false */
if (typeof someVar === "undefined") {
    var someVar = "hi!";
}
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Note that the `var` is not scoped to the `if` block. It's as if you had written `var someVar` above the `if`. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: Went down a huge rabbit-hole after reading only the code in the answers here, and not the one in the question. If you want to write code that works on both Nodejs and the browser, this *is* the correct way to check if a variable is undefined, regardless of what JSLint may think about it.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
/*global window */

if (window.someVar === undefined) {
    window.someVar = 123456;
}

if (!window.hasOwnProperty('someVar')) {
    window.someVar = 123456;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `/*global window */`, you could use `/*jslint browser: true */`.

Comment: To have the same result, the second solution should actually be `if(!window.hasOwnProperty('someVar'))`

Comment: what if a the page runs this script before yours : `undefined = 'some value'` ?

Comment: @gion_13 `undefined = 'some value'; console.log(undefined);` still gives `undefined`.

Comment: @gms8994 newer browsers don't let you overwrite the `undefined` *constant*.

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi: Don't use `.hasOwnProperty()` for this. It can fail.

Comment: `.hasOwnProperty()` is [a lot slower](http://jsperf.com/check-for-declared-global-in-vs-typeof).

Comment: Note that "window" itself is not defined in a web worker. For max compatibility, check the presence of window first.

Comment: @CrazyTrain it can fail specifically because it might be overridden in the scope chain. There are ways to get around it, and to @alex-w's point, even if it is a lot slower, it also returns the correct value. Solution: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, 'someVar')`

Comment: this assumes that the javascript code in question is running in a browser

Comment: Why are there two conditions in this answer? Are both really required, and why?

Comment: @Offirmo Any thoughts on how to do that? In that case, `window` is a global variable, whose existence we want to check - which of course is the problem we'd like to solve in the first place.

Comment: Backbone does it.  Here is URL to annotated 'backbone' source (see "root", at very beginning of code): https://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html

Answer (score 16):

```
/**
 * @param {string} nameOfVariable
 */
function globalExists(nameOfVariable) {
    return nameOfVariable in window
}
```

It doesn't matter whether you created a global variable with var foo or window.foo — variables created with var in global context are written into window.

Comment: Of course, you don't have to use a function, you can simply use `"foo" in window` anywhere

Comment: Hrmmm, JSlint says: `Unexpected 'in'. Compare with undefined, or use the hasOwnProperty method instead.` Then, I guess, the right way is:

    `window.hasOwnProperty("nameOfVar")`

Comment: @Susei: jsLint is incorrect. The `.hasOwnProperty()` is faulty because there can be a global that is further down the prototype chain of `window`. It's still a global variable, but `.hasOwnProperty()` won't see it. The `in` or  `undefined` tests are the way to do it.

Comment: This won't work in a NodeJS terminal; `window` is undefined there.

Comment: good answer for a React app where you might want to have an inline check in your JSX

Answer (score 14):

If you are wanting to assign a global variable only if it doesn't already exist, try:

```
window.someVar = window.someVar || 'hi';
```

or

```
window['someVar'] = window['someVar'] || 'hi';
```

Comment: This is the most elegant and cleanest solution.

Comment: This will not work as expected if the global variable is falsy. If `someVar` contains a value like `0` or `''`, it will assign `'hi'` to it instead of using the existing value.

Answer (score 9):

try

```
variableName in window
```

or

```
typeof window[variableName] != 'undefined'
```

or

```
window[variableName] !== undefined
```

or

```
window.hasOwnProperty(variableName)
```

Comment: Did you try to test these on JSLint? "'someVar' in window", "typeof window['someVar'] !== 'undefined'", "window['someVar'] !== undefined" (without converting it to "window.someVar !== undefined) are not Okay on JSLint. But anyway, thanks for your great answer :)

Comment: `"prop" in object` is absolutely legal JavaScript. Remember, JSLint is for you, not you for JSLint, and JSLint is not a JavaScript. For me `if ('prop' in obj) { do_it(); }` is more clear (i.e. readable and maintainable), then `if (obj.prop !== undefined) { do_it(); }`. I would suggest you to ignore JSLint in this case. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824895/jslint-error-unexpected-in-compare-with-undefined-or-use-the-hasownproperty.

Comment: You are absolutely right but I rather to keep my codes JSLint validated because it is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is actually a problem with JSLint. It will issue the following error:

> Unexpected 'typeof'. Compare directly with 'undefined'.

I believe this is bad advice. In JavaScript, `undefined` is a global variable that is, usually, undefined. But some browsers allow scripts to modify it, like this: `window.undefined = 'defined'`. If this is the case, comparing directly with `undefined` can lead to unexpected results. Fortunately, current ECMA 5 compliant browsers do not allow assignments to `undefined` (and will throw an exception in strict mode).

I prefer `typeof someVar === "undefined"`, as you posted, or `someVar in window` as Susei suggested.

Comment: Particularly relevant today because not all JS will run in a browser. If you are writing a library you want your code to work both against the browsers as well as runtimes like nodejs where window does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> if (typeof someVar === "undefined") {
>     var someVar = "hi!";
> }
> ```

will check if `someVar` (local or global) is undefined.

If you want to check for a global variable you can use

```
if(window['someVar'] === undefined) {
    ...
}
```

assuming this is in a browser :)

Answer (score 6):

As of ES6 most of other answers, including the accepted answer, are incorrect, because global variables defined by `let` or `const`, or resulting from a `class` declaration, do not have corresponding properties on the global object (`window` in a browser, or `global` in node.js).  Several of them—mainly the ones which use `typeof`—can also be fooled by global variables which exist but which are set to `undefined`.

The only fully general way to test to see if a global variable exists—regardless of whether it has been declared using `var`, `let` or `const`, created via a `function` or `class` declaration, created by assignment (i.e., `myVar = value` at the top level of a program without any declaration for `myVar`) or by creating a property on the global object (i.e., `window.myVar = value`)—is to attempt to access it via a global `eval` and see if TypeError is thrown.

(This builds [on an idea presented by Ferran Maylinch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432729/4969945), but with a trick to ensure that it will work properly even when encapsulated in a function.)

```
function globalExists(varName) {
  // Calling eval by another name causes evalled code to run in a
  // subscope of the global scope, rather than the local scope.
  const globalEval = eval;
  try {
    globalEval(varName);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

undeclared = undefined;
const myConst = undefined;
let myLet;
var myVar;

globalExists('undeclared')    // => true
globalExists('myConst')       // => true
globalExists('myLet')         // => true
globalExists('myVar')         // => true
globalExists('nonexistent')   // => false
globalExists('globalExists')  // => true - can see itself.
globalExists('varName')       // => false - not fooled by own parameters.
globalExists('globalEval')    // => false - not fooled by local variable.
```

Note that this makes use of `eval`, so all the usual caveats apply: you should not supply an untrusted value as the parameter, and if you must use an untrusted value you should check to make sure that `varName` is a valid JavaScript identifier.  Doing so is out of scope for this question, but it can be done using a [(rather complex) regular expression](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/javascript-identifier-regex)—just beware that the correct regexp depends on the version of ECMAScript you are using, whether the code is a script or (ES6) module, whether it is in an async function, etc. etc.

Comment: Interesting, good catch on `log` and `const`. I was curious about `eval` and, if `varName` is not provided by a user, I guess it should not be a dangerous usage to evaluate a variable name? How can it be weaponized?  
Anyway I found this interesting part on [MDN: never_use_eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) and `eval` can be replaced with ```Function(`"use strict";return ${varName}`)();
```
I've tested it and works just as fine!

Comment: @Gruber: globalExists has the same safety properties as `eval`: that is, it is perfectly safe as long as its argument is never controlled by a hostile actor.  If you only ever pass string literals that are valid variable names, for example, then it is harmless.  I think [never use eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) is not a highlight of the MDN documentation: the `Function` constructor is no safer than `eval`, I am skeptical about the claimed speed advantage, and the `globalEval` trick is just as good for scope control.

Answer (score 1):

bfavaretto is incorrect.

Setting the global undefined to a value will not alter tests of objects against undefined. Try this in your favorite browsers JavaScript console:

```
var udef; var idef = 42;
alert(udef === undefined); // Alerts "true".
alert(idef === undefined); // Alerts "false".
window.undefined = 'defined';
alert(udef === undefined); // Alerts "true".
alert(idef === undefined); // Alerts "false".
```

This is simply due to JavaScript ignoring all and any values attempted to be set on the undefined variable.

```
window.undefined = 'defined';
alert(window.undefined); // Alerts "undefined".
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the Answers section just to disprove another person's answer. If you don't think another person's answer works, either comment on their answer as to the problem(s) you foresee so they can fix it, or offer your own valid solution to the question.

Comment: This is relevant, but it doesn't answer the question. I realize this is too long to post as a comment, perhaps you could also _answer_ the question below your disagreement?

Comment: You could have left a comment on my answer just to let me know you disagree, I only saw your answer by accident. You're kind of right about our "favorite browsers", the problem is that older browsers didn't prevent that. I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, despite restrictions in modern browsers, `undefined` can still be modified: this function is perfectly legal: `function foo(undefined, x) { if (x === undefined) { alert('undefined!'); } }`. It will _not_ alert if you call, for instance, `foo(3)`. The lesson is that 'undefined' is not always a reference to the global property.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a simple way to perform the check .

But this check would fail if `variableName` is declared and is assigned with the `boolean value: false`

```
if(window.variableName){

}
```

Comment: This does not work if `variableName` has any falsy value (for example emtpy string), so this might not be a sufficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is the following:

```
if(window.hasOwnProperty('foo')) {
    console.log('Variable is not declared');
}
```

The following solution will not work if the variables is declared but is not assigned (var foo;).

```
typeof foo === 'undefined'
```

Comment: I swore I've seen code that threw an error on `typeof` when the variable is undefined, But `typeof` seems to work everywhere now. Interactively from node (`node -e "console.log(typeof foo === 'undefined')"`), in the devtools console (`console.log(typeof foo === 'undefined') // true`) and from a file (`node test.js // true`) Even in with `"use strict";`

Answer (score -1):

If you are not sure whether a global variable is defined, you can always try accessing it and see what happens.

```
function node_env(name) {
    try {
        return process.env[name];
    } catch (ignore) {}
}
```