# Why jslint complains about this code and how should I fix it

Tags: javascript, jslint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jslint error: Unexpected 'in'. Compare with undefined, or use the hasOwnProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824895/jslint-error-unexpected-in-compare-with-undefined-or-use-the-hasownproperty)

Why jslint complains about this code and how should I fix it.

```
            if ('children' in object) {
                for (key in object.children) {
                    recurse(object.children[key], key);
                }
            }
```

Obviously recurse is defined.

Comment: What does jslint complain about? Please include the warnings.

Comment: The complaints of JSLint are exactly the reasons: "Unexpected 'in'. Compare with undefined, or use the hasOwnProperty method instead.".

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a var. Also, you are not using "hasOwnProperty".

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
    for (var key in object.children) {
        if(object.children.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            recurse(object.children[key], key);
        }
    }
}
```